# Collection of Foreign Keys in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dapper

I have a scenario where an object with properties stored in a table row will need to include a collection of Foreign Keys from another table.

I.E. a Room will have a multiple Sources. Ideally this collection of sources would be a list of foreign keys and the 1 to many relationship will be created by queries against the Sources table.

What is the correct way to store a list of Foreign Keys in a single row column?

The equivalent Json structure would be something like:

```
{
    Rooms: [{
        “Name”: ”Some Room”,
        “Sources”: [“Source ID1”, “Source ID7”, “Source ID3”]
    }]
}
```

Rooms Table:

```
|ID | Name | More Props..| SourceIds |
```

Comment: "What is the correct way to store a list of Foreign Keys in a single row column?" - the correct way is Don't! I'm not going to explain how FK's work. A simple internet search will answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rooms Table:

| ID | Name | More Props |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Room1 | ... |
| 2 | Room2 | ... |

Sources Table:

| ID | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SourceID1 |
| 2 | SourceID7 |
| 3 | SourceID3 |

RoomSources Mapping Table:

| RoomID | SourceID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

To get all the sources for Room1, you could use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT s.Source 
FROM RoomSources rs 
JOIN Sources s ON rs.SourceID = s.ID 
WHERE rs.RoomID = 1;
```

Comment: This could certainly work. However It might get fairly large as there could be 10-20 rooms each containing 2-20 sources.

Comment: @EricWilliams: That's not large....

Comment: Fair, but for what it’s worth this is running on a SQLite db on a small Linux arm device with minimal memory and storage.

Comment: Please explain what are you gonna do later with the list of FK. I have an idea, but to implement it I need to see further.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a class {

```
  Rooms: [{
        “Name”: ”Some Room”,
        “Sources”: [“Source ID1”, “Source ID7”, “Source ID3”]
    }]
}
```

and serilize it.

```
var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourclass>(response);
    return outObject;
```

Comment: Mostly to protect the data integrity with valid foreign keys. I original considered a stored blog of json but it defeats the purpose of a relational database. I can certainly validate things on the way in and out, but it just feels wrong.